# Does sync.Once.Do guarantee visibility across goroutines?

Tags: go

The example [here](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_9) implies that sync.Once.Do guarantees visibility across goroutines for the string var a. Is that also true if for example the function f() called by sync.Once.Do initializes multiple fields of a struct instance? Will all the fields of the struct instance be visible to other goroutines without any additional synchronization?

Comment: You're asking for a testable situation. Why not try and test it yourself? It's a good learning moment :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the behavior of sync.Once, it has to do with the visibility of what your `f()` does. (I guess you could mess it up by copying the Once value too)

Comment: f() initializes the fields of a struct that other goroutines will then read. I think the answer is that if all the other goroutines also go through the same Once.Do call then they will see the writes that happened in f(), but if they do not, e.g. they get passed a pointer to the struct instance and they never call Once.Do (on the same Once instance of course) they are not guaranteed to see the writes. Correct?

Comment: No. `sync.Once` ensures the argument of `Do` is called once, and only once. It does *nothing* else. Any other synchronization you need is up to you to provide.

Comment: Is the example wrong then? It claims it prints "hello world" twice but if there's no guarantee that the 2nd goroutine sees the write to the a var, the claim is not correct. Or is there something else at play here that I'm missing?
https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_9

Comment: @JimB `sync.Once` does more than ensuring that the argument of `Do` is called once.  Per the [memory model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2), `Do` also establishes a before relationship between the execution of the function and the return from `once.Do()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the [example](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_9):

The variable `a` is set *before* the function `setup()` returns because reads and writes within a single goroutine must behave as if they executed in the order specified by the program [[1](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2)].

The single call to `setup()` from `once.Do()` happens *before* any call of `once.Do()` returns [[2](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_2)].

Therefore, the variable `a` is set *before* any call to `once.Do()` returns. No further synchronization is required to establish this before relationship.

The question asks about struct fields, not a single variable as in the example. As far as the memory model is concerned, struct fields are variables. All of the logic that applies to  the variable in the example applies to fields in a struct.

Comment: Is the example wrong then? It claims it prints "hello world" twice but if there's no guarantee that the 2nd goroutine sees the write to the a var, the claim is not correct. Or is there something else at play here that I'm missing? http://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_9

Comment: @user2526241 the example isn't wrong, as long as you call .Do(f) before reading the variable then the variable will be set.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for, clarification that no extra synchronization is required to ensure visibility. I assume it will work the same for more complicated structs with multiple fields in place of the simple "var a string".

Comment: @Muffin Top, Thanks for answer. I would like to understand how happens-before relationship is established. If we look at the implementation (https://golang.org/src/sync/once.go), once .Do(f) returns o.done is set to 1 and other goroutines calling .Do(f) returns immediately without acquiring any locks. So I wonder how other goroutines see the complete value of variable a. I know atomic.LoadUint32 does not establish happens before. Can you please shed some light here.